# Calculate average of 4 numbers ignoring null values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the average of 4 numbers in SQL.
The condition is if any of the 4 numbers are null, those numbers should not be considered for calculating average

Like (12,null,null,3) should give 15/2 = 7.5
Any number in the list can be null

Comment: provide sample input and sample output. Are these 4 values in different rows or same row ?

Comment: They are just variables that are declared and assigned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may unpivot the values using `VALUES` table-value constructor and then get the average of the values using `AVG()`. The `AVG()` function will ignore the `NULL` values:

```
SELECT AVG(x)
FROM (VALUES (12.0), (NULL), (NULL), (3.0)) v (x)
```

If the values are stored in a table, you need an additional `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (12.0, NULL, NULL, 5.0),
   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
   (1, 1, 1, 10.0)
) d (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)


SELECT *
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT AVG(Col) AS Col
   FROM (VALUES
      (d.Col1), (d.Col2), (d.Col3), (d.Col4)
   ) v (Col)   
) a
```

Result:

```
Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4 Col
-----------------------------
12.0  null null 5.0  8.500000
null  null null null null
1.0   1    1    10.0 3.250000
```

Answer (score 0):

The average function in sql avg() does not take into account the null values.So,you can use avg() function in the query to calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

    AVG (CASE WHEN Value <> 0 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)
    ....
```

AVG won't take into account NULL values. Or this

```
AVG (NULLIF(Value, 0))
```

Comment: Who said anything about 0?